# Alternate models to Hadoop/MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Recently there was an [article](http://gigaom.com/cloud/why-the-days-are-numbered-for-hadoop-as-we-know-it/#comment-861667) in GigaOm about the Hadoop days being numbered and with a number of different alternatives like [Percolator](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36726.html), [Dremel](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36632.html) and [Pregel](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1807184).

[Apache Hama](http://hama.apache.org/), [Apache Giraph](http://giraph.apache.org/), [GoldenOrb](http://goldenorbos.org/) and [GraphLab](http://graphlab.org/) are some implementations of Pregel. I would like to know if there are any open/closed source implementations of Percolator and Dremel.

Answer (score 2):

There is open source project to build dremel compatible database (Disclaimer - I am part of the team). 
I am suggesting to start reading from here about it:
http://bigdatacraft.com/archives/327

Comment: From the blog entry it seems that OpenDremel has been put on hold for now.

Comment: Not exactly, we decided that lightweight virtualization is required to build such systems (zerovm) so we worked on it.  Otherwise we do not believe multi-tenant analytics is possible. Storage integration is also needed to gain data locality, so we integrated with the Swift.Having done these two tasks now we are getting back to implementing dremel encoding and execution tree inside ZeroVM.